# can pure virtual function have definition or return type "void"?

Tags: function, pure-virtual

My Question is :

Can a pure virtual function have return type VOID ?/
or you can can is it true that a pure virtual function can only have a return type "VOID"?

Second question is : 
Can a pure virtual function have definition ?
or a pure virtual function can have definition is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a pure virtual function can return void.

No, a pure virtual function cannot have a definition.  The "pure" in "pure virtual" means that it has no default definition.